# R - the simplest way to move legend when plotting raster

Tags: r, plot, r-raster

I need to plot raster files.

In my output image, numbers on the legend are sometimes not visible - especially when I split graph window to two or more columns (for example: par(mfrow=c(1,2))).

I thought about moving legend to the bottom (below raster image) to resolve this issue.
However, most examples which I found suggest creating completely new legend with completely new colors and items definitions.

I would like to use the default legend. I just need to move it to the bottom. I've tried to do this as follows:

```
library('raster')
data(volcano)
r <- raster(volcano)
# Trying to draw default legend below raster plot
plot(r, legend=F)
# Now trying to draw legend. Default is okay for me, I want to move it below only:
plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, legend.args=list("bottom", text='My values [m^3]'))
```

Unfortunately, my code is not working (seems "bottom" parameter is not used).

[image: What I need to achieve]

Comment: Have you come across any way to modify the color of the legend text?

Comment: No, I don't need to change the color of the legend text.

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr

Try passing `horizontal = TRUE` to the `plot()` function call.

```
library('raster')

data(volcano)
r <- raster(volcano)

plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, horizontal = TRUE, legend.args = list(text='My values [m^3]'))
```

[image]

### Tweaks

You can now pass `side=` or `line=` arguments to the `legend.args` list to specify where you want the legend label (default is `side = 3` and `line = 0`). For instance, you could put the "My values [m^3]" text below the legend by using `side = 1` and space it a bit further from the legend (versus on top of it!) using `line = 2`.

```
plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, horizontal = TRUE, 
        legend.args = list(text='My values [m^3]', side = 1, line = 2))
```

### Advanced tweaks

If you want to plot the legend somewhere other than the right or bottom of the plot, you'll have to look into first plotting your raster with `axes = FALSE` and then plotting it again but passing as arguments `legend.only = TRUE` and `smallplot= c(xleft, xright, ybottom, ytop)` to specify where in the plotting region to draw the colored box.

### Background

The trick is that the `legend.args` list gets passed to the `mtext()` function, so the standard way of defining legend locations in base `R` plotting with the `legend()` function and using the `x=` argument (e.g., "bottom", "bottomright") isn't available.

You might think that the `axis.args` list would help, since that also (counterintuitively perhaps) controls how the legend is drawn. The `axis.args` list is passed to the `axis()` function to draw some features of the legend, and the `axis()` function has a `side=` argument that sets which side of the plot the axis (in our case the legend) will be drawn! But no, the `side=` argument is set by other means during the drawing of the raster plot.

What means are those you might ask? It's the `horizontal=` argument!

The `horizontal=` argument can be passed to the `plot()` call to say whether you want the raster legend to be on the right of the plot (the default, `horizontal = FALSE` sets the `side=` argument to 4 in the `axis()` function call that draws the legend) or on the bottom of the plot (when `horizontal = TRUE` which sets the `side=` argument to 1 in the `axis() function call that draws the legend)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116818/how-to-change-position-of-legend-in-levelplot-of-rastervis-in-r) is a way using `rasterVis`:

```
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, colorkey=list(space="bottom"), par.settings = RdBuTheme())
```

[image]

Comment: Outside of `rasterVis` is there a way to modify the text color of the legend? I am using `smallplot` to place my legend inside my plot

Answer (score 0):

Or try `spplot`, which also uses package `lattice`:

```
spplot(r, scales = list(draw = TRUE), colorkey = list(space = "bottom"))
```

Comment: This works, but I also add some shapefiles to my raster, for example: `plot(punktyPom,add=T, lwd=c(1), lty=c(1))` and `spplot` seems to not work properly